# bash script case statements not working using dialog

Tags: bash

I've been experimenting with dialog and bash scripting lately.  I created a dialog menu with three options: Users, Passwords, and Groups then also a quit option.  I'm trying to run functions for each of these in a case statement but it always seems to fall through to the catchall last statement and output the echo "Something Else..." statement regardless of which option I choose instead of say running the echo statements in the related function, e.g. echo "Entering Users sub-menu"

I've tried running this with debugging on:

```
bash -x myscript
```

and I get the following output:

```
+ choice='Users
Error: Expected a box option.
Use --help to list options.'
+ '[' 'Users
Error: Expected a box option.
Use --help to list options.' '!=' ' Quit ']'
+ case $choice in
+ echo 'Something else.  Where Am I?'
Something else. Where Am I?
+ exit 0
```

I'm still trying to figure out what "Expected a box option" means which sounds like its related to dialog but I'm also wondering if there's something broken with my if statement or case statement in bash.

the code to my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

function quit {
    exit 0
}

function menu {

choice=$(dialog --backtitle "Rob Graves's Bash Scripting" \
--title "Main Menu"  --menu "Choose one" 30 50 4 "Users" \
"- Do something with users" "Passwords"\
 "- Do stuff with passwords"  "Groups" "- Do things with groups" \
 "Quit" "- Exit to desktop" --clear --nocancel 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)

    if [ "$choice" != "Quit" ]; then

        case $choice in 
            Users)
                users                   #calls users function
                ;;
            Passwords)
                passwords               #calls passwords function
                ;;
            Groups)
                groups                  #calls groups function
                ;;
            *)
                echo "Something else.  Where Am I?"
                ;;
        esac

    else
        echo "Quitting..."
        quit
    fi

}

function users {
    echo "Entering Users sub-menu"
}

function passwords {
    echo "Entering Passwords sub-menu "
}

function groups {
    echo "Entering Groups sub-menu"

menu

exit 0
```

Comment: Note -- a quick drop-in replacement providing a GUI for the dialog is xdialog (the command is `Xdialog`). Another option for your scripts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your immediate options seems to be that `dialog` command does *not* like the options `--clear` and `--nocancel` options at the end as you have mentioned. Re-ordering it seems to work fine as expected

```
choice=$(dialog --backtitle "Rob Graves's Bash Scripting" \
                --title     "Main Menu" \
                --clear \
                --nocancel \
                --menu  "Choose one" 30 50 4 \
                "Users"     "- Do something with users" \
                "Passwords" "- Do stuff with passwords" \
                "Groups"    "- Do things with groups" \
                "Quit"      "- Exit to desktop" 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)
```

Also it would be good idea to always quote your `case` option strings as below

```
case "$choice" in
    "Users")
        users                   #calls users function
        ;;
    "Passwords")
        passwords               #calls passwords function
        ;;
    "Groups")
        groups                  #calls groups function
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Something else.  Where Am I?"
esac
```

Also remember you can also add options for `"Users"` as `"1 - Users"` in both the `dialog` menu and in the `case` menu as below.

[image]

and in `case` statement as

```
case "$choice" in
    "1 - Users")
```

---

Also note that the commands [users(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/users.1.html) and [groups(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/groups) are standard commands available as part of GNU `bash` and using the same name for functions has a possibility of bringing an uncertainty. Always choose names that are unambiguous.

Remember to exit the script with a non-zero exit code on failure cases from the script. For e.g. on the default case above, remember to add an `exit 1`, so that it adds one other way of debug facility to look in, when the script exits abnormally, *not* running the expected flow of sequence.

```
    *)
        echo "Something else.  Where Am I?"
        exit 1
        ;;
```

When this is hit and when your script exits and doing `echo $?` would have shown the code returned.

Also drop the non-standard `function` keyword from the function definition in the script. As long as the script runs in `bash` shell it should be fine, on a pure POSIX only shell, the keyword might not be recognized.

Also you should use **`#!/usr/bin/env bash`** for [portability](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Shebang_(Unix)&oldid=878552871#Portability): different *nixes put `bash` in different places, and using `/usr/bin/env` is a workaround to run the first `bash` found on the `PATH`.